# How to enable compression for ssl in apache2?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.2

We enabled SSL for our site, but now the client (Chrome browser) is reporting that content is not compressed. How to check if it is working? How to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

SSL Compression isn't recommended but you enable it with directive `SSLCompression on`

More information:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#SSLCompression